# How to refer to query string param in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My lambda can use `events["zip_code"]` when testing it in the management console and configuring the test event to have that.

How can I configure my APIgateway to pass zip_code ?

I've tried hundreds of different approaches over several hours.  this should take about 30 seconds to figure out!

Current (stripped down) attempt:

I create a lambda.  It can refer to `event[zip_code"]` no problem.  I create an API Gateway that points to it and I can call it.  However every attempt I make to refer to the query string parameter in the lambda has failed.

I have tried:

```
event["zip_code"]
event["query_parameters"]["zip_code"]
event["queryStringParameters"]["zip_code"]
```

but they all give nil.

I've tried publishing my lambda (probably needed) and I've tried deploying my API to a particular stage, 'DEV' but neither seemed to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to access query string parameters in Lambda using `event["queryStringParameters"]["zip_code"]` as long as `Use Lambda Proxy integration` is checked. If not, then you will need to set up custom mapping. In most of the use cases, proxy integration is the recommended option.

[image]

[See docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html)

> In Lambda proxy integration, when a client submits an API request, API
>   Gateway passes to the integrated Lambda function the raw request
>   as-is, except that the order of the request parameters is not
>   preserved. This request data includes the request headers, query
>   string parameters, URL path variables, payload, and API configuration
>   data

Non proxy integration requires [custom mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integrations.html).

> In Lambda non-proxy integration, in addition to the proxy integration
>   setup steps, you also specify how the incoming request data is mapped
>   to the integration request and how the resulting integration response
>   data is mapped to the method response